# How do I remove elements from each row of an array?

Tags: r

I have a matrix/array with M rows, N columns.

I want to remove elements from each row based on whether a condition is satisfied or not for that element (for example if `x > 1 & x != 5`).

Note that the number of removals is different for each row, so I won't end up with a matrix anymore: each row will have a different number of elements after we are done.

But that's okay, then I just want all those rows in a suitable array.

How to do this efficiently in R?

Comment: if @akrun's answer solves your problem, you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`.  If the number of elements returned are not the same, it will return a `list` of `vector`s instead of `matrix`

```
lst1 <- apply(M, 1, function(x) x[x > 1 & x !=5])
```

---

Another option would be to keep the structure as such, but change all other elements to `NA`

```
M[!(M > 1 & M !=5)] <- NA
```

Most of the functions have arguments `na.rm` which takes a boolean `TRUE/FALSE` to remove the `NA` from analysis.  or with `na.omit` on the row or the whole matrix or with `complete.cases` to remove the `NA` rows